# How to insert data into MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have 3 tables.

> 1. A users table with just an id and a name.
> 2. A students table with id, name and subject.
> 3. A students_enrolled table which is now empty.

I want find all table entries from 'users' table which have matches in 'students' table.  For this I have the following query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    students
WHERE   name  IN (SELECT name FROM users);

QUERY RESULTS:

id  name
3   mark
4   steve
```

> This works but now the GOAL is to pupulate the third table
>   ('students_enrolled') with this data and have the ids match the users
>   table.
>
> In the users table 'mark' is ID 3 and 'steve' is ID 4, but in the
>   students table they are IDs 50 and 99 respectively. I want to insert
>   them into the 'students_enrolled' table with matches IDs to the users
>   table.  *Note: the 'names' will always be unique - there will never be
>   two steves within one table*.  Also, if a match is found I would like the 'status' field to have the entry 'enrolled'.

```
The goal is to have the 'students_enrolled' table show this:

id  name    status  subject
3   mark    enrolled    math
4   steve   enrolled    reading
```

I have created a sqlfiddle with all the schema and data if someone has any ideas here:

[SQL Fiddle Link][1]

```
Schema:

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'john'),
    (2, 'jane'),
    (3, 'mark'),
    (4, 'steve');

-- ----------------

CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `students` (`id`, `name`, `subject`)
VALUES
    (50, 'mark', 'math'),
    (99, 'steve', 'reading');


-- ----------------

CREATE TABLE `students_enrolled` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


/* Desired result:*/
/* INSERT INTO `students_enrolled` (`id`, `name`, `status`, `subject`)
VALUES
    (3, 'mark', 'enrolled', 'math'),
    (4, 'steve', 'enrolled', 'reading'); */

-- ----------------
```

Comment: It should be `user_id` as foreign key, instead of creating the `name` column everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like

```
INSERT INTO students_enrolled (name,subject)
SELECT  s.name, s.subject
FROM    students s
JOIN users u ON s.name = u.name;
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul! You got me almost all the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully working query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `students_enrolled` (`id`, `name`, `status`, `subject`)
SELECT u.`id`, s.`name`, 'enrolled', s.`subject`
FROM `students` AS s
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON s.`name` = u.`name`;


SELECT *
FROM `students_enrolled`;
```

Cheers!